# How to use a variable which is an integer as a rand value in query?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want to execute a select query on database and use it as a random value

```
$randomElement = rand(0,$room_number);
$query="SELECT * FROM set_ballot";
$rs=  mysqli_query($cn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
  $room_number = $row['room_number'];
}
```

what I'm trying to achieve is that I want an admin to input a number and the number can be used to display a random number between 0 to the number the admin inserted e.g.: `0,50`

Comment: why not just use `RAND()` in your query instead? Or must you use a PHP method?

Comment: @fred im new to programming, please how can i use it ?

Comment: I.e.: `SELECT * FROM set_ballot ORDER BY rand()` with optional `LIMIT x_integer`

Comment: thanks for your reply, what im trying to achieve is i want an admin to input a number and the number can be use to display a random number between 0 to the the number the admin inserted e.g 0,50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is using the `$room_number` variable before you defined it.

So first, you should set the variable to the desired value, in your case you get it from your database

```
$query="SELECT * FROM set_ballot ";
$rs=  mysqli_query($cn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
  $room_number = $row['room_number'];
}
```

Now that the variable `$room_number` is defined you can use it

```
$randomElement = rand(0,$room_number);
```

So in the end your code would look like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM set_ballot ";
$rs=  mysqli_query($cn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
 $room_number = $row['room_number'];
}
$randomElement = rand(0,$room_number);
```

Comment: @fred it said i must have 15 reputation